# trying to create Leaflet map dynamically on a card that open and close

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Hi there I am trying to make an info card for a trip (not real just practice), I want that a Leaflet map will show once the user clicks on the card as part of info card, but I not able to make the map show dynamically.

---

Is it possible?

Should  I  use promises and await? if yes how?

Or should I try useing the google map API instead?

This is the HTML CSS and JavaScript
(the js i mostly took  from a youtube video but i modified it to work in my code)

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const mapInfo = [
    {curessTitle : "Big City",
    mapLat : 51.505,
    mapLon : 0,
    },
    {curessTitle : "Food",
    mapLat : 51.505,
    mapLon : 0,
    },
    {curessTitle : "Nature",
    mapLat : 51.505,
    mapLon : 0,
    },
    {curessTitle : "Culture",
    mapLat : 51.505,
    mapLon : 0,
    },
    {curessTitle : "Pepole",
    mapLat : 51.505,
    mapLon : 0,
    },

];
        
        const toggleExpansion = (element, to, duration = 350) => {
          return new Promise((res) => {
            element.animate([
              {
            top: to.top,
            left: to.left,
            width: to.width,
            height: to.height
              }
            ], {duration, fill: 'forwards', ease: 'ease-in'})
            setTimeout(res, duration);
          })
        }

        const fadeContent = (element, opacity, duration = 300) => {
            return new Promise(res => {
                [...element.children].forEach((child) => {
                    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                        child.style.transition = `opacity ${duration}ms linear`;
                        child.style.opacity = opacity;
                    });
                })
                setTimeout(res, duration);
            })
        }

        // this is the part where I am trying to add the Leaflet map dynamically
        const createMap = (cardDataIndex) => {
            return new Promise(res =>  {
            const cardContentDiv = document.querySelector(".card-content");
            const creatMapDiv = document.createElement("div");
            creatMapDiv.id = "mapid";
            cardContentDiv,appendChild(creatMapDiv);
            
            const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([mapInfo[cardDataIndex].mapLat, mapInfo[cardDataIndex].mapLon], 13);

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(mymap);   
        
            setTimeout(res, 1000 )
            }) 
            
        };
        

        const getCardContent = (title) => {
            return `
            <div class="card-content">
            <h2>The ${title}</h2>

            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
             Dolorum voluptates sequi modi at voluptatibus.
              Tempora iste laudantium nemo sequi soluta nobis aut ex molestias quos,
               dicta, quas est iure odio?</p>
             
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>the routs</h2>
             

           </div>
        </div>
            `;
        }

        const onCardClick = async (e) => {
            const card = e.currentTarget;
            const cardDataIndex = e.currentTarget.dataset.index;
            const mapLat = mapInfo[cardDataIndex].mapLat;
            const mapLon = mapInfo[cardDataIndex].mapLon;
            
    
            // clone the card
            const cardClone = card.cloneNode(false);
            // get the location of the card in the view
            const {top, left, width, height} = card.getBoundingClientRect();
            // position the clone on top of the original
            cardClone.style.position = 'fixed';
            cardClone.style.top = top + 'px';
            cardClone.style.left = left + 'px';
            cardClone.style.width = width + 'px';
            cardClone.style.height = height + 'px';
            // hide the original card with opacity
            card.style.opacity = '0';
            // add card to the same container
            card.parentNode.appendChild(cardClone);
            // create a close button to handle the undo
            const closeButton = document.createElement('button');
            // position the close button top corner
            
            ////// mybe creat the map after----->
            closeButton.style = `
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 15;
                top: 10px;
                right: 10px;
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: #e25656;
                outline: none;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            `;
            // attach click event to the close button
            closeButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
                // remove the button on close
                closeButton.remove();
                // remove the display style so the original content is displayed right
                cardClone.style.removeProperty('display');
                cardClone.style.removeProperty('padding');
                // show original card content
                [...cardClone.children].forEach(child => child.style.removeProperty('display'));
                fadeContent(cardClone, '0');
                // shrink the card back to the original position and size
                await toggleExpansion(cardClone, {top: `${top}px`, left: `${left}px`, width: `${width}px`, height: `${height}px`}, 300)
                // show the original card again
                card.style.removeProperty('opacity');
                // remove the clone card
                cardClone.remove();
            });
            // fade the content away
            fadeContent(cardClone, '0')
                .then(() => {
                    [...cardClone.children].forEach(child => child.style.display = 'none');
                });
            // expand the clone card
            await toggleExpansion(cardClone, {top: "0", left: "auto", width: '100%', height: 'auto'});
            const content = getCardContent(mapInfo[cardDataIndex].curessTitle, mapLat, mapLon)
            // set the display block so the content will follow the normal flow in case the original card is not display block
            
            cardClone.style = ` 
                                position: absolute;
            
                                display: flex;
                                padding: 0;
                                background:  #333;
                                color: #ffffff;
                                z-index: 10;
                                opcity: 1; 
                                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                                flex-wrap: wrap;
                                `
            
            // append the close button after the expansion is done
            cardClone.appendChild(closeButton);
            cardClone.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', content);
            
            //createMap(cardDataIndex);
        };

        
            


 cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', onCardClick));
```

```css
*  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {

    --color-primery:  #F09819;
    --color-primery-dark: #e48f18;
    --color-secondery: #5b86e5;
    --color-error: #cc3333;
    --color-success: #4bb544;
    --border-radius: 4px;

    font-family: sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #F09819, #FF512F);
}

header{
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background: white;
}    

nav{
    min-height: 10vh;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}

nav h1,
nav ul {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    flex:1; 
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}


nav  a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.login-account-continer{
    margin-left: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.login-btn{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.account-btn{
    font-size:25px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:  #eeeeee;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin: 1rem;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox; 
}




.flex-curess-container{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5%;
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    justify-content: center; 
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.close-info{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: coral;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card{
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 230px;
    
    height: 400px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border:none;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 10px #333;
    cursor: pointer;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5 ease-out;
}

.active {
    max-width: none;
    height: 800px;

}


.card .image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.card .image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover .image img{
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
.card:hover .hover-img-info{
     opacity: 0.9   ;
}


.hover-img-info {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(51, 51, 51, 1) ;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    

  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .2s ;
}

.hover-img-info h3{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 25px; 
}

@keyframes slideDown {
    100%{
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}


.card-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px 25px 25px;
    margin: 5%;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 45%;
    height: 90%;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 wrap;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
.card-content > * {
    transform: translateY(-35px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.card-content h2 {
    font-size: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 35px !important;
    animation: slideDown 0.5s ease-out forwards;
}

.card-content p {
    color: #fff;  
     overflow: auto;
    animation: slideDown 0.5s ease-out 0.4s forwards;
}

#mapid {
    height: 300px;
    animation: slideDown 0.5s ease-out 0.4s forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Japan-Travel-site-cursses-page.css"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""/>
            


     <script async  src="Japan-Travel-site-cursses-page.js"></script>
     <script async src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

            <style>
            
            #mapid { height: 180px; }
            
            </style>
    <title>Japan Travel Curess Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>Travel Japan</h1>
            <ul class="ul-nav">
              <li><a data-page="home" href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="login-account-continer">
                <span class="login-btn">Login</span>
                <a href="#"><div class="account-btn"></div></a>
                
            </div>
            
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        
        <div class="flex-curess-container">
            <div class="card item1"  data-page="big-city" data-index="0">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?city   " alt="tokyo">
                </div>
                <div class="hover-img-info">
                    <div class="close-info"></div>
                    <h3>The Big City</h3>
                    <div class="coures-info">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Quis magnam dolorem vero voluptatum similique tempore cumque iste harum officia! 
                        Similique recusandae magni voluptas quod deleniti porro voluptatum ab quisquam perferendis.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card item2" data-page="food" data-index="1">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?japan-food   " alt="food">
                </div>
                <div class="hover-img-info">
                    <h3>The food</h3>
                    <div class="coures-info">
                        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Esse sequi dicta earum architecto obcaecati adipisci eius reprehenderit distinctio itaque laboriosam.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card item3" data-page="nature" data-index="2">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?japan-art   " alt="art">
                </div>
                <div class="hover-img-info">
                    <h3>The Nature</h3>
                    <div class="coures-info">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Quis magnam dolorem vero voluptatum similique tempore cumque iste harum officia! 
                        Similique recusandae magni voluptas quod deleniti porro voluptatum ab quisquam perferendis.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card item4" data-page="culture" data-index="3">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?japan-culter  " alt="tokyo">
                </div>
                <div class="hover-img-info">
                    <h3>The Culture</h3>
                    <div class="coures-info">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Quis magnam dolorem vero voluptatum similique tempore cumque iste harum officia! 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card item5" data-page="pepole" data-index="4">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?japan-people   " alt="people">
                </div>
                <div class="hover-img-info">
                    <h3>The Pepole</h3>
                    <div class="coures-info">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Quis magnam dolorem vero voluptatum similique tempore cumque iste harum officia! 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        


    </main>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, you should consider simplifying your code to what is really triggering the issue, when posting it as a question. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ghybs ok i will try it thank you so much  i will read it ! and I will improve  my questions, do you have more  information  on  writing  questions  correctly  on stack overflow ? i will love to learn, again  thank you .